# Bundling a reusable library with systemjs builder

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, jspm, systemjs

My brain has melted trying to bundle code for a reusable library and I need someone to steer me back on the path.

I've written a library in TypeScript that I want to reuse in multiple projects using jspm.

It has a single entry point file called Index.js which exports just one class I want to expose (Class1).

**Index.js**

```
export { Class1 } from "./Classes/Class1";
```

The problem is that when I bundle this to a single file using systemjs-builder it dumps all of the dependencies in there.

**Build output:**

```
System.register("Classes/Class2.js", [], function(exports_1) {

});

System.register("Classes/Class1.js", ["Classes/Class2.js"], function(exports_1) {

});

System.register("Index.js", ["Classes/Class1.js"], function(exports_1) {
});
```

I don't believe an SFX bundle is suitable because I want to load this with systemjs, so there are a few things here I don't understand.

1. I don't want to expose class2 (it's just a dependency of class1) - but it looks to me from the output like anyone could just `require` it if they wanted to.
2. What about module ID clashes? What if I have another 3rd party library that also defines a Classes/Class1 module?

What I essentially want is a single file that exports only the modules I require and nothing else and is namespaced so that it doesn't clash with any other libraries. How can I achieve this?

Comment: I have not tried it myself but I believe that the --format option for bundle-sfx command can help you: e.g. jspm bundle-sfx main test-b.js --format amd|cjs Also see the issue about interoperability of bundles  https://github.com/jspm/jspm-cli/issues/786